# permutation of 2 strings in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation

I want to write a program that gives 2 strings(char type) and combine them in different ways. 
for example if 2 strings are "abc" and "mn" the program should print :
abcmn abmnc amnbc mnabc mabcn mannbc mabnc ambnc ambcn abmcn .
As you see they should be in ordered form in each string. I mean that for example "c" couldn't be before "a" or "n" couldn't be before "m".
what can I do?

Comment: what if "abc" and "cd"? can one of the "c" be in front of "a"?

Comment: because they are same there is no problem.

Comment: it's ok but you wrote an extra "d" !

Comment: sorry, "acbcd". I am writing "an answer" now

Comment: ok.I'm waiting... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As I don't know much about `c++`, I am not able to write a full code this problem, but I will describe the idea and algorithm as below.

Since we need to keep the order of the chars in each string, we can think the process of building the combinations like this (using your example `abc` and `mn`):

---

- let's consider the last element first in each possible combination:
  it is either `c` or `n`. So we can build a list with two element
  list: `[['c'];['n']]`.
- Then let's have a look at the second last element:

  If `c` is the last element, then the possible second last elements
  are `b` and `n`, right?

  If `n` is the last element, then the possible second last elements
  are `c` and `m`, right?

  So let's extend the previous list to
  `[['b';'c'];['n';'c'];['c';'n'];['m';'n']]`
- If continue to the third last element in the same way, we will have

  `[['a';'b';'c'];['n';'b';'c'];['b';'n';'c'];['m';'n';'c'];['b';'c';'n'];['m';'c';'n'];['c';'m';'n']]`
- Continue up you will get the full list.

---

Here is the ocaml code just in case you know functional programming

```
let rec comb_2 l1 l2 =
  let insert x = List.map (fun y -> x::y) in
  match l1, l2 with
    | [], [] -> [[]]
    | hd::tl, [] | [], hd::tl -> comb_2 tl [] |> insert hd
    | hd1::tl1, hd2::tl2 ->
      (comb_2 tl1 l2 |> insert hd1) @ (comb_2 l1 tl2 |> insert hd2)
```